# How to Move a Project to parent project folder in Github

Tags: eclipse, github, github-for-mac

Folder structure

JavaRepo/Struts1

Want to change this like

JavaRepo/StrutsProjects/Struts1

Please suggest how to move project into subfolder in GitHub

Comment: Take a look at the following questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401952/github-folder-structure-change

And:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293089/changing-the-git-structure

Comment: If i dont use command, any other way plz?

Comment: What do you mean by "dont use command?"
How else would you have Git do what you want?

Comment: I mean if i am not using command prompt using git. Till now i have using eclipse to git stash for code commit, so not aware of using git by its commands. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106288/how-to-move-egit-repository-and-working-directory